# @font-face works locally and not working while using url

Tags: html, css, font-face

This code works fine on my single HTML page, both the HTML file and the font are in the same folder.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFont;
    src: url(DroidKufi-Regular.ttf);
}
```

Now i'm trying to add the font in the website and use the link in the code.

```
src: url("http://hnauae.com/myFonts/DroidKufi-Regular.ttf");
```

This one isn't working, can anyone explain me why?

Comment: What's the console error you're receiving?

Comment: try using a relative path instead of absolute path.

Comment: Are you using https on the website? If you use https, the `src` needs to be https too, to prevent CORS errors

Answer (score 1):

Import url make page loading slower than normal loading.
use your resources local

and use relative path like below:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: url('fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin-webfont.svg#robotothin') format('svg');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
    /*other custom  styles*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you try to add in website use relative path

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try to use a relative path rather than a relative path.

> Note that it will depend on your file structure.

Change

```
src: url("http://hnauae.com/myFonts/DroidKufi-Regular.ttf");
```

To

```
src: url("../myFonts/DroidKufi-Regular.ttf");
```

Comment: if i use this code, src: url("../myFonts/DroidKufi-Regular.ttf");